# How to reposition a fixed widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, layout, widget, position, augmented-reality

I'm building an AR app with Flutter and using the [ar_flutter_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/ar_flutter_plugin).

The position of the AR widget seems to be fixed to the top left and it doesn't move anywhere else. Whatever the other widgets in the tree, doesn't change anything. It's always at top left corner (see image).

It works with a dummy widget just fine (compare second img).

Child Ar widget

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        width: widget.width,
        height: widget.height,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ARView(
                    onARViewCreated: onARViewCreated,
                    planeDetectionConfig:
                        PlaneDetectionConfig.horizontalAndVertical,
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment(1, 1),
                    child: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: takePicture))
              ]),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Parent Widget

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      key: scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryBackground,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 350,
                height: 350,
                child: ObjectsOnPlanesWidget(
                  // child: custom_widgets.ArPlaceholder(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  modelUrl: widget.modelUrl,
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-0.23, -0.92),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(8, 24, 8, 24),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color:
                              FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).secondaryBackground,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        ),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () async {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.chevron_left,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            size: 24,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Try On',
                        style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyText1,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color:
                              FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).secondaryBackground,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        ),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.share_outlined,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          size: 24,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0.95),
                child: Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).secondaryBackground,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  ),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.photo_camera,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: 24,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: The fixed positioned AR-widget]

[image: The dummy container which works as intended in the background]

I want to put the camera in the background and put other widgets (such as photo-taking-button) on top of it.

How do I reposition it into a container? At least under the App Bar?

Comment: Can you include the parent class too please? I mean where you added the appbar

Comment: Hey @KaushikChandru, added the build of parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically this should have worked, what i would suggest you try would be to first have a SafeArea widget.

```
SafeArea(
child: build(buildContext),
),
```

I had a similar issue in the past and using this solved it.

Also, there seems to be [an open issue](https://github.com/CariusLars/ar_flutter_plugin/issues/110) which seems related to this with the following possible solution :

```
With Flutter 2.10.5. it works without problems. This seems to be a Flutter 3 problem.
The way platforms views are rendered was changed in the 3.0 release.

probably same issue:
flutter/flutter#106246
explained here:
flutter/flutter#103630

I hope this will be fixed in new Flutter 3 releases soon.
```

And also this

```
I try the master channel Flutter v3.1.0-0.0.pre.1372 and the issue is fixed there.

Fixed will come to a stable channel soon with Flutter v3.1.0.
```

Also, I am not sure why are you using SizedBox as your parent widget.

Why not try a basic Container instead?

Good luck, Let me know if I can help with anything else

Comment: Hey @FreakyAli, thanks for the tip, but the parent already uses the SafeArea.

Comment: I have also added more details I got from the plugin's git you might wanna check those out I guess could be a possibly similar issue for you. Trying the pre flutter SDK would be 1 thing i would check out

Comment: It was the issue...Thanks!